# Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: Module system:main is not found in local module loader @6267c3bb

Tags: java, jboss

I'm trying to start jboss 7.0.1 Final on eclipse and I'm getting below error

> WARNING: -logmodule is deprecated. Please use the system property
>   'java.util.logging.manager' or the 'java.util.logging.LogManager'
>   service loader. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: Module system:main is not found in
>   local module loader @6267c3bb (roots:
>   C:\Users\f5142067\jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\modules)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:78)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1193)     at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:522)     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:326)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:390)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:242)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:527)    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>     at
>   __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:100)   at
>   __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:83)    at
>   __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:70)    at
>   __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory.changeDefaultFactory(__DocumentBuilderFactory.java:80)
>     at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.changeAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:43)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:257) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was
>   removed in 8.0

Comment: JBoss AS 7 does not work with Java 8. You'd need to move to WildFly for Java 8 support.

Comment: i  managed to get it working using java 7, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit the part where you invoke Java and add the argument `--add-modules java.se`:

exec "$JAVA" **--add-modules java.se** $JAVA_OPTS (...)

Or if you are on Windows, use the `.bat` instead of the `.sh` file!

Answer (score 0):

```
Below are possibilities which you can check :

1).Correct installation of modules which requires creating a path under the JBOSS_HOME/modules folder. Under this path, you will install the JAR libraries which are part of the module and a module.xml file which describes the module itself and dependencies with other module.

2).Check the name of the dependency in <your-app>/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" file .
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating '**lib**' folder at following location: \wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\artemis\main